# refresh my adapter

Tags: android

I have a list of students that I display in an adapter
that I create in the class MyCustomAdapter.
Here is the class ManageSection where I call the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete record from your **list which you pass to your custom dapter adapter(i think studentList is your list)** and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` Method.

**Edit :**

```
if (stdel == false) 
{
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error deleting student, Please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

if(stdel==true)
{
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: so you mean that studentList(student id ) in class MyCustomAdapter and what about notifyDataSetChanged() where i call it

Comment: @MaramWatban Call it after delete record from list.

Comment: @MaramWatban Call  notifyDataSetChanged(); after student.remove() in do background method.

Comment: in your code if stdel == true then it not go to in that loop and not call notifydata set changed method.

Comment: so what should i do also do i keep the studen.rem... or not

Comment: have question  i do not use ArrayAdapter i use ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> student; dose the same function i can do by first remove and then    notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to call notifyDataSetChanged() method of adapater. It will refresh the whole list.Try It.!

Comment: where i can use it in class of the adapter or calss that call the adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

use `adapter.notifyDatsetChanged();`

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example) too

see this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)